# Align Horizontally the Images in Bootstrap Carousel and Do Not Limit the Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2 for Carousel:

```
    <div id="pageCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
        <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="image1.jpg"/>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="image2.jpg"/>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="image3.jpg"/>
                </div>

        </div>

        <!-- carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#pageCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#pageCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is to align images horizontally. And also to display the full height of the images.

Comment: what do u mean by full height of images?

Comment: If you want to align images horizontally first define a div container divide that into two vertical div classes based on height and width auto. Then inside of top div class divide total space into 4 div classes as per your wish height and width.In each div class inside place your image as per your wish.

Comment: i mean `full height` the actual height of the images